# Laravel appends only one attribute from relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to add an extra field to my Laravel 7 API model:

```php
class Layer extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'filename', 'status', 'category_id'];

    protected $appends = ['category_name'];

    public function getCategoryNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->category->name;
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LayerCategory', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```php
.....
public function index()
{
    return Layer::orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(); 
}
.....
```

I expect the following response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "category_id": 1,
  "name": "My Layer",
  "filename": "file_name.zip",
  "status": true,
  "category_name": "My category name"
}
```

But I receive:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "category_id": 1,
  "name": "My Layer",
  "filename": "file_name.zip",
  "status": true,
  "category_name": "My category name",
  "category": [
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My category name",
    "status": true
  ]
}
```

How to return only the category name?
PS: I also tried with Resources.

Comment: what code return those object?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert, I've added the controller method in the question. Thanks!

Comment: You are lazy loading the category relationship with this code `$this->category...`

Comment: if you don't want to see the `category` object, you will have to use a join query instead os using `appends`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're eager loading the `Category` relationship to get `category_name`, you'll need to add logic to hide `category` from your JSON response. This can be done using the Hidden attribute on Serialization:

```
protected $hidden = ['category'];
```

You can read https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json for more information.

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you!